# How to convert ip like `127.0.0.1` to `127.0.0.0/24` use regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have a file that save lots of ip, and now I want to convert them like `127.0.0.1` to `127.0.0.0/24` use regex. I've tried something like this:

```
re.sub('\.*\n', '/24\n', f.read())
```

but it only add `.0/24` after the ip(like convert `127.0.0.1` to `127.0.0.1.0/24`), and if I add a `.` after `\.` like this:

```
re.sub('\..*\n', '/24\n', f.read())
```

then `127.0.0.1` will be convert to `1/24`.

Comment: Are you sure the mask is `/24`? Some ip ranges are `/16`, `/8`, etc.

Comment: @CommuSoft Well, I don't know about it. Could you tell me about it please?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork) is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
re.sub(r'\.\d+($|\n)', '.0/24\n', f.read())
```

Comment: And by the way, please change `'0/24\n'` to `'.0/24\n'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a more *detailed* regex:

```
>>> ip='127.0.0.1'
>>> re.sub('([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)', r'\1.\2.\3.0/24', ip)
'127.0.0.0/24'
```